# Would you like a hat for the holidays?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange is looking to have some fun for the holidays by giving people hats for various tasks around the site. These, unfortunately, aren't real hats, more like holiday badges that you can see on your gravatar. They hosted a holiday hat bash on the Gaming site [last year](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), and have asked if other sites would like to opt-in or out of being included in the event this year. There's an option for individuals to opt out, so if you're Jeff Atwood and don't want a hat messing up your hair, there's no cause for alarm.

Is there anyone that objects to this event for DIY?

Here's a example user page with the hats:

[image: user page]

Comment: Give me teh hatz!

Comment: They're looking for [hat suggestions on SFF meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2420/27); is that something we could try for here?

Comment: Looks like fun, would you be up for starting that meta post, @NiallC.? Note that there's no guarantee that SE will use any suggestions we make, but we can always ask.

Comment: @bmitch OK, I'll post one later today.

Comment: I want a pirate hat....    hehehe

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no objection, I'm opting us into the holiday hats.