# Any objections to virtual winter hats for 2013?

Tags: discussion

Like [last year](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/727/2196), SE is doing their Winter Hat promotion again. There is an opt out for anyone that individually doesn't want to participate, but my plan is to opt in our community unless there are significant objections.

The hats come out from December 16th until January 3rd. You'll be able to see all of the hats at http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com once the event starts. If you have a deep hatred of hats, there will be a "I hate hats" link in the footer that will allow you to individually opt out.

Comment: Was surprised to hear recently that JFK single-handly killed off hats for men in the early 60s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no objections, I'm opting us into the hats.

Comment: HATS!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yay Hats!!!!! (I hate the minimum character requirement of comments; sometimes less is more.)

Comment: Wait. Where is YOUR hat?

Comment: Apparently it's only on the main site, not on meta. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

...and what in heck is the deal with "secret" hats (F.I. the "Chuck Yeager" helmet (which looks a bit "Russian Air Force" for General Yeager, IMHO, but anyway...) - secret even from the people who get them, and wonder why...

Comment: Only thought I have is they are from moderating and SE doesn't want to encourage excessive or inappropriate moderating just to get a hat. E.g. one of mine may have come from deleting a spammer and we don't want to encourage mods to find a user they can delete just to get a hat.

Comment: And now the answer to the secret hats has been posted on the blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/